# Can I boot with a secure USB key

Tags: boot, security, bootable

**Can I boot with a secure USB key if a Linux distribution is installed on it?**

Example of secure key ( Aegis secure USB ):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Most secure USB are powered and are decrypted without being plugged.

[image]